# Visibility of py_library targets in sub-folders

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-python

I'm trying to add a custom build rule that will automatically add all the targets (python files) in each sub-folder to the dependencies for a `py_binary` in a BUILD file.

Here is the folder structure of my project:
`/my/project/src/subdir1/`
`/my/project/src/subdir2/`
`/my/project/src/subdir3/`
`/my/project/src/subdir4/`
`/my/project/src/subdir5/`

Each subdir/ folder has its own BUILD file with the package `default_visibility` set to public for the `py_library` targets in that folder.

The python source file for the `py_binary` and the respective BUILD file are in the `/my/project/src/` folder. In the custom build rule under `/my/project/src/`, I'm trying to use glob() to add the path for each target in each sub-folder to the dependencies for the `py_binary`  in the BUILD file. However, the targets in a sub-folder aren't visible to the custom build rule unless I remove the BUILD file in that sub-folder.

Custom Build Rule:

```
    def compute_deps():
        pattern = ["**/.*py"]
        all_files = native.glob(pattern)
        print(all_files)
        deps = [convert_path_to_target(filepath) for filepath in all_files]
        return deps

    def custom_build_rule(name, main, srcs):
        deps = compute_deps()
        return py_binary(
            name = name,
            main = main,
            srcs = srcs,
            deps = deps
        )
```

When I run `bazel query //my/project/...` in the terminal, all the targets in each sub-folder are listed, so I don't understand why these targets aren't visible to the custom build rule.

Answer (score 0):

The `glob` function cannot traverse past subpackage boundaries, which explains the behavior you see.

You may be able to put something working together with the [`subpackages`](https://bazel.build/reference/be/functions#subpackages) function, which can list all subpackages of the current package but not any targets within them.

Comment: Is there a function I can use to see the targets within each sub-package? glob() returns an empty list.

Comment: No, you'd have to make a convention that the subpackages have a `everything` target or something similar.